# Shopping cart price rules do not apply to configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I have a configurable product that has 12 associated products. One of those associated products needs to be part of a promotion.

Let's say the SKU for the configurable is J001 and the SKU for the simple product is J001-2D.

The attribute in the promotion is Container Size. The configurable doesn't have that attribute, but the associated products do.

If I create a shopping cart price rule that looks like the following:

[image: promotion]

That doesn't match anything. If I exclude everything (IE, Container Size Is Not *whatever*), it matches everything in the cart. This says to me that the promotion isn't matching the simple associated product.

Is this intended behavior? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Wouldnt this work out of the box. I mean cart rules validate the *simple* products - the problem we have is the opposite. We need to validate the parent attributes instead of the simple ones .... was this behavior changed in Magento?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently Magento does not support this by default. Instead, we overrode Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator and created a salesrule rewrite. In that we check to see if the associated product matches the sales rule.

*app/code/local/AAA/SalesRule/etc/config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AAA_SalesRule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </AAA_SalesRule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <aaa_salesrule>
                <class>AAA_SalesRule_Model</class>
            </aaa_salesrule>
            <salesrule>
                <rewrite>
                    <validator>AAA_SalesRule_Model_SalesRule_Validator</validator>
                </rewrite>
            </salesrule>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/AAA/SalesRule/Model/SalesRule/Validator.php*

```
* * *

private function _hasChildInCart($product){
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product);
    $childrenIds = $this->_getChildrenIds($childProducts);

    foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
        if(in_array($item->getProductId(),$childrenIds)){
            $registeredItem = Mage::registry('rule_config_product_'.$product->getId());
            if($registeredItem != null && $registeredItem->getId() != $item->getId()){
                Mage::unregister('rule_config_product_'.$product->getId());
            }
            if($registeredItem == null){
                Mage::register('rule_config_product_'.$product->getId(),$item);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private function _getChildrenIds($childProducts){
    $childrenIds = array();
    foreach($childProducts as $child){
        $childrenIds[] = $child->getId();
    }

    return $childrenIds;
}

* * *
```

Comment: Thx @Alex : how/where is this method called? and/or is the extension downloadable?  --- maybe also add a pull request here: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/blob/1.9.3.x/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php